# Is there an equivalent to Eurocodes for other types of devices or machines?

Tags: eurocodes

Is there an equivalent to Eurocodes for other types of devices or machines? Such as robots, scientific instruments, electronics, ...

Comment: Like ISO or BS?

Comment: Have you actually checked them for relevance or just commented?

Comment: @SolarMike Yes I think ISO sounds quite like it. Not sure about BS.

Comment: Do you understand what BS is?

Comment: @SolarMike Seems related to ISO somehow. Considering it had C++ standardization in Wikipedia, then maybe it's relevant to this question.

Comment: Many standards set by many countries are "related" to ISO - like the British Standards BS that I referred you to.

Comment: Perhaps a valid context to the question would be though that other than civil and building engineering might not be as easy to standardize due to varying requirements and the multitude of parts.

Comment: The CE mark regulation is similar in purpose and function to the eurocode 'harmonized technical rules'.

Comment: @mavavilj In some sense, Eurocodes are tailored to varying requirements more than most other standards, because of varying environmental loads like wind, snow and earthquake. In other areas of engineering, conditions may be very different, but usually much more predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are similar codes and standards for various types of devices and machines. For example:

- Robotics: ISO 10218, Safety requirements for industrial robots, provides safety requirements for robots and robotic systems.
- Scientific Instruments: ISO 15190, Medical laboratories - Requirements for quality and competence, covers the quality management of medical laboratories and the requirements for competence of testing and calibration laboratories.
- Electronics: IEC 60601, Medical electrical equipment - Part 1: General requirements for basic safety and essential performance, provides requirements for electrical medical equipment and systems.

These standards and codes are specific to their respective industries and provide guidelines for design, manufacturing, and performance of devices and machines, ensuring their safety and reliability.

Comment: Eurocode is a code for the use of ISO standards. It specifies, among other things, which standards should be used, and how. It's not equivalent to an ISO standard.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  Poor choice of works on my part.  I edited to say "similar" codes instead of equivelant.

Comment: @david Eurocode is not a single standard. Eurocodes are a set of civil engineering CEN standards starting with designations EN 199x. They, like many other standards also reference other standards (and definitely not just ISO). ISO and CEN [cooperate](https://www.cencenelec.eu/about-cen/cen-and-iso-cooperation/) to avoid duplicate standards thanks to the [Vienna agreement](https://boss.cen.eu/media/CEN/ref/vienna_agreement.pdf).